# Custom placing of multiple time-axes in fullcalendar weekly view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I know that its possible to have multiple time-axes in fullcalendar. In the default settings (for v2.1.1), there are two time axes, with the second one appearing after the sixth day.

Is it possible for me to set the appearance of axes to be more frequent - say, after every 2 days? Or, if I were to somehow have a week with custom number of days (3,4,5,etc), to have the second time-axis in the middle of the week.

The current state of things, and the behaviour I'm after are displayed below.

Current behaviour:[image]

Desired behaviour:[image]

I've looked at the fullcalendar.js file, but have no idea what to change.

Comment: I'd guess this would probably be a fairly complex change. Rather than modifying fullCalendar.js you would probably do it by making a [custom view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js) (you could start with the code of the existing time grid view and modify it, of course). But even then there's a lot to think about. If you're going to invest that amount of time and effort, don't do it on version 2.1 - it's ancient and hasn't been supported for a while. Version 4 is the current version.

Comment: @ADyson The trouble is, this version of fullcalendar is a part of an old (but still active) project. Still, thank you for the advice, it's certainly something to think about.

Comment: That's annoying. But not insurmountable. I don't know how much calendar code you've got but replacing it with v4 is unlikely to be the end of the world (especially compared to the effort of writing a custom view). There's even a migration guide on the website to help you.